# Html5 canvas animation. How to reset rectangle when it hits the end

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hey Im experimenting with some html5 animation and so far I have a square that "falls" whenever I press the button. I was wondering how i could have it go back to the top when it hits the bottom and fall again.
My current code is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="400" style="border:1px solid black;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
function draw (x,y){
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.save();
var side = 10
var up = 10
ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,400);
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,up,side);
ctx.restore();
y += 5;
var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',30);
}


</script>
 <button onclick="draw(0,0)">draw</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your variables `y`, you can simply check if it is below the height of the canvas height.

```
if( y > c.height ){ // use the canvas height, not the context height
   y = 0;
}
```

Also, the way you're currently calling the timer is a bit inefficient. Instead of :

```
var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',30);
```

I would recommend

```
var loopTimer = setTimeout(function(){ draw(x,y); },30);
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vwcdpLvv/

Comment: Thanks, bit of a noob here... Where would I put the if statement in my code to make it work?
edit: just saw your example, Thanks!

Comment: @ReedJohnson If you look at the jfiddle I put it after you update the position. But frankly, you could put it anywhere in the draw function and it would work nearly all the same. ---> Also, it's supposed to check if it's greater than `>`, not smaller than`<` I had to fix that error.

Comment: Hey! I was messing with this a bit more and I was wondering how to make the square bounce back... I tried changing the y = 0 to y -= 5 in the if statement but it just started glitching out... any ideas?